# Calling func of another view controller to control alpha returns nil error

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, parent, uicontainerview

I have a (parent) view controller that has a container view within it. When app is started, it first goes to the parent, then it goes into the container view. Within the container view controller I try something like parentName().changeAlpha() - this is a function belonging to the parent... which should change the alpha of a label on the parent view.

However, it keeps giving me a nil error as soon as I attempt to call that function. Please keep in mind the parent view is being loaded first thing.

Hierarchy: (I have the Xcode name of each controller followed by the file name belonging to it in parenthesis)

**Tab Bar Controller** (TabBarController) (There are 3 tabs)

**Tab1** (homeScreenContainer) - Contains a view controller with a uiviewcontainer within it. Also **contains the function that I am trying to call.**

All part of container view:

- **Page View Controller** (2 Pages total, first page is the one below) (RootPageViewController)

  - **View controller** (ViewController) - **this is where I am trying to call the function.**

---

Tab2 (Irrelevant)

Tab3 (Irrelevant)

Also, the only inheritance in both the code and the storyboard is only the uiviewcontainer (and there is no code inheritance involved there).

Comment: Please add code for the `changeAlpha` method and what the nil error in the console says. It would also be helpful to know where you're calling changeAlpha from, what method is that being called from within?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this

```
parentName().changeAlpha()
```

Creates another object of parent other than the shown one , and it gives nil error as the VC should be loaded from Stroyboard/Xib not like this `parentName()` except if it's programmatically created , what you really need is querying the window for it , suppose the parent is the rootVC of the window you can do this

```
if let tab = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
      print("Inside Tap")
   if let realParent = tab.viewControllers![0] as? ParentVC {
     print("Inside Parent")
     realParent.changeAlpha()
   }
}
```

Comment: hmmm I tried ur solution and now I no longer get a nil error, However, (it doesn't get a nil error because...) it doesn't actually call the function (I tried print lines). any ideas?

Comment: ok i need to know your window hierarchy , does the root is a navigationController ? tabbar ? or what ?

Comment: tabbarcontroller>tab item/view controller that has a container view>root page controller>view controller that calls the function that exists in the tab item/view controller (2nd item in hierarchy)

Comment: hmm it's still not calling the function.

Comment: does the first tab is the parent ??

Comment: ill edit my question in a sec of the hierarchy so its easier to see

Comment: any navigationcontroller embed in first tab ??

Comment: No, but it's technically not the initial view controller. Theres a view controller that quickly transitions to home screen container (Think of a launch screen)

Comment: no launch isn't embed in the window , ok can you force unwrap the casting above to help know the type of the VC ??

Comment: ooo it is the custom launch screen (which is just a normal view controller)

Comment: btw it is a login screen not a launch screen, so it goes loginscreen>then I programmatically transfer to homeScreenContainer

Comment: Any more ideas?